# ASP.NET 5 on Azure Docker on Ubuntu Server

Tags: c#, azure, ubuntu, docker, asp.net-core

I'm deploying my ASP.NET Core application using Docker. I've everything is up and running, I've successfully pushed it to the Docker Hub. Now I've created a new Azure Docker VM "Docker on Ubuntu Server in Container Services." I SSH in to that machine, pulled my Docker image from the Docker Hub but when I expose a port the same as I do on my local machine, it does not work (Timeout connection error occurs) but the same image works on my local machine.

Please someone can Identity the problem? Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet:1.0.0-rc1-update1-coreclr
```

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN ["dnu", "restore"]

EXPOSE 5000

ENTRYPOINT ["dnx", "-p", "project.json", "web"]

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the dockerfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you haven't setup your Endpoint in Azure.
Please have a look here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-classic-portal-use-docker/
Go to: Add the Docker Communication Endpoint
There you have to put your port into it.

Then it should work. Hopefully :)

Comment: Thanks, I did not configure VM's endpoints. This was the problem.